# How to pass parameter in javascript closure and keep it memory without the help of outer environment?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, closures

I have a scenario like i will call a function from one place and it will emit function in other place.But i also need parameters of first function without passing through the function  in between.
So i thought there might be a way to do that using closure.So guys help me out in this implementation.

```
 var add = (x)=> {
   var counter = x;
     return function (c) {counter += c; return counter}
   };
   add(5)(2);
   add()(2); //Assuming the value of 5 is someway inside the parent's memory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set a global variable

```
var map
```

Then you can use the map reference anywhere:

```
var map; //global variable to be access anywhere

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 8
  });

  //add the listener to the map within the initMap
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    placeMarker(event.latLng);
  });

}

//this function is calle when the button is clicked which calls the placemarker function outside the init
function addMarker(){
        placeMarker({lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644});
}


//this can now be called from anywhere
function placeMarker(location) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map
  });
}
```

**JSFIDDLE**: https://jsfiddle.net/vy9seg3b/1/